# Need help with making a website where user can add products

Tags: themes, templates, user-registration, responsive, static-website

I need help and advice how to make an website where user register and add products to the sites. 
There shouldn't be any paying function, just a user interface and the products that users add can be seen by others (users and not users). The products have to be categorized. 
What would be the best base template for this kind of website?
And which plugins to use?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3):

This is generally not the type of question to ask here. Try searching the [WP plugin repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/). I'd take a close look at [Woocommerce](https://woocommerce.com/) and it's [extensions](https://woocommerce.com/product-category/woocommerce-extensions/).

Answer (score 0):

The best 2 plugins you can use are [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) and [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Custom post type UI will give you the option to easily create another post type, like "Products" and assign it to specific user role.

Advanced Custom Fields, will allow you to add some extra fields to the newly created post type, like Price, Stock and so on.